# Monitoring incoming requests on a web hosting server

Tags: linux, networking, post, webserver

I have a web hosting account with GoDaddy (its a Linux based hosting). Can I install applications like netcat to monitor all incoming requests to my website on a certain port? If not, is there any other way I can do that?

I have a page that accepts POST data, and I need to send the POST data from hardware level. I'm sending the data but apparently its not in the correct format. I want to be able to see the exact request being received on the server end in raw HTTP form, and be able to compare it against the request received when sent through another web page to look for discrepancies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have root access on your server, you can install and run Wireshark. Wireshark will analyze and display the data from the HTTP connection.

Comment: I do have root access. I'll look into wireshark. Thanks.

Comment: In the alternative, you can install Wireshark on *some* web server (a Linux PC in your basement, a virtual PC running on your laptop, whatever.) You could watch *that* data -- maybe that would help.